# R selectInput reactivity issues

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am having trouble with reactivity in Shiny. In my UI, I have

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(forcats)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(h1("Percent Cover")),

  selectInput("selectInput", "Select Site", choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), 


plotOutput("coverTypeBarChart", height = "600px")

)
```

These correspond to dataframes  A, B, C, D which I read in at the top of the server.

In my server, I have:

```
 colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "purple")



reactive({

    if (input$selectInput == "A")
    {data <- A}
    else if (input$selectInput == "B")
    {data <- B}
    else if (input$selectInput == "C")
    {data <- C}
    else if (input$selectInput == "D")
    {data <- D}

 })


    data() <- na.omit(as.data.frame(data()$cover_group))
  names(data()) <- c("tmp")

  cover_group_factor <- as.factor(data()$tmp)

 cover_group_factor <-  fct_recode(cover_group_factor, OTHER = "E", OTHER = "F", OTHER = "G", OTHER = "H", OTHER = "I", OTHER = "J", OTHER = "K")

    bar <- ggplot(data = data()) +
            geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cover_group_factor, y = ..count../sum(..count..)), fill = colors) + xlab("Cover Group") + ylab("Percent")




 observe({
   output$coverTypeBarChart <- renderPlot(bar)
        })

}
```

I know when I manually assign data to any of the values,  and manually run the code, I can produce the plot, so I know it's a reactivity issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say too much as I don't have examples of the data frames. However, from what I see, I can't see that you've attached anything to your reactive function. Could it be that you need to say the following? 

`data <- reactive({

    if (input$selectInput == "A")
    {data <- A}
    else if (input$selectInput == "B")
    {data <- B}
    else if (input$selectInput == "C")
    {data <- C}
    else if (input$selectInput == "D")
    {data <- D}

 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to solve a similar problem. For the following example, I made up some data:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
A <- sample_frac(mtcars,0.2) %>% select(cyl)
B <- sample_frac(mtcars,0.2) %>% select(cyl)
C <- sample_frac(mtcars,0.2) %>% select(cyl)
D <- sample_frac(mtcars,0.2) %>% select(cyl)
```

Here's the simplest version of your `ui`, which has an `input` and `output`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
          selectInput("choice", "Select Site", choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), 
          plotOutput("barchart", height = "600px")
      )
```

The trick I use is to retrieve the data.frame you want by `name` with `get`. For instance:

```
get("A")

                 cyl
Merc 230           4
Merc 450SE         8
Fiat 128           4
Porsche 914-2      4
Valiant            6
Pontiac Firebird   8
```

In the context of `server`:

```
server <- function( input, output ) {
               output$barchart <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = get(input$choice), aes(cyl)) + geom_bar())
          }
```

As you can see in my `ggplot` statement above, I'm retrieving the data given by `input$choice` using `get`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with p0bs - you'll need to assign the result of your `reactive` expression to a variable.

Also, nested `if...else` statements have specific syntax. `else` must be on the same line as the closing braces of the `if` statement.

Here's something that might work:

```
data <- reactive({
    if(input$selectInput == "A"){
        A
    } else if(input$selectInput == "B") {
        B
    } else if(input$selectInput == "C") {
        C
    } else if(input$selectInput == "D") {
        D
    }
})
```